# PYTHON/pypandoc: Can pypandoc be used to convert Rmd files to html?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, markdown, pypandoc

I'm trying to write python code that can convert an rmd file to html. Rmd was not listed as one of the built in formats for pypandoc, so I tried to use regular markdown for the format parameter.

```
output = pypandoc.convert_file(
            f"{file_path}/{file}", 'html', format = 'markdown', outputfile= f"{file_path}/{file}.html", encoding = 'utf-8')
```

But I get the error that it could not be converted "[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math site."

Is there another way to convert the file without changing the TeX math?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the style of TeX math content used in the Rmd file, but if you used dollar signs, something like this should work

```
output = pypandoc.convert_file(
    f"{file_path}/{file}",
    'html',
    format='markdown+tex_math_dollars',
    outputfile=f"{file_path}/{file}.html",
    encoding='utf-8'
)
```

You can find examples for other styles (e.g. single backslash) here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-tex_math_single_backslash

Also, you can take a look at https://pypi.org/project/knitpy/ which is a port of `knitr` for Python, as there are elements of RMarkdown which won't be recognized by pandoc.